# How do I serialize hash format:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord, hash

I have the following data:

```
 [{"uid"=>"12406664"}, {"uid"=>"13715056"}, {"uid"=>"20911274"}, {"uid"=>"20921750"}, {"uid"=>"144901695"}, {"uid"=>"200002261"}, {"uid"=>"583131545"}, {"uid"=>"584667098"}, {"uid"=>"585043552"}, {"uid"=>"593713530"}, {"uid"=>"645734146"}, {"uid"=>"649596998"}, {"uid"=>"663955553"}, {"uid"=>"698033741"}, {"uid"=>"1024899231"}, {"uid"=>"1032611215"}, {"uid"=>"1076202442"}, {"uid"=>"1168728549"}, {"uid"=>"1283882122"}, {"uid"=>"1296965460"}, {"uid"=>"1417999220"}, {"uid"=>"1420197620"}, {"uid"=>"1455766774"}, {"uid"=>"1479820827"}, {"uid"=>"1568075339"}, {"uid"=>"100000804563736"}, {"uid"=>"100001055926570"}, {"uid"=>"100001633945205"}]
```

How do I store this data using Ruby on Rails? I'd like to keep the data accesable, where

```
>> x[1]
=> {"uid"=>"13715056"}
```

Currently I'm using a postgreSQL heroku server, I have the User.user_id column serialized as a Hash and the data is a mess:

```
"[{\"uid\"=>\"12406664\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"13715056\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"20911274\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"20921750\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"144901695\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"200002261\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"583131545\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"584667098\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"585043552\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"593713530\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"645734146\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"649596998\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"663955553\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"698033741\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1024899231\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1032611215\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1076202442\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1168728549\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1283882122\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1296965460\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1417999220\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1420197620\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1455766774\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1479820827\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"1568075339\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"100000804563736\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"100001055926570\"}, {\"uid\"=>\"100001633945205\"}]"
>> User.last.uid.last
=> "]"
```

How can I correct this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can serialize as you wish: `Hash`, `Array`, custom class... you're quite free.

As of your expectations, serialize as an `Array`.

Comment: SerializationTypeMismatch -(variable was supposed to be a Array, but was a String) what's going on?

Comment: :) as I said before, you can even store data in a custom class. It may help